# How we can get metadata regarding Salesforce Dynamic form layouts using Ui-api or other rest api

Tags: page-layout, dynamic-forms, summer-21

I am trying to test and implement dynamic form layout for a mobile App(Custom App). For page layouts metadata I was using Ui-api. But metadata for dynamic form layouts is not in Ui-api. Where we can look for metadata regarding dynamic form layouts.

Comment: I am also trying to get dynamic form layouts(fields and section)metadata for my custom component. Can I get these layout info using apex metadata?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Forms is not yet available for Mobile, unfortunately. However, the Record Detail - Mobile component gives your mobile users a way to see the record details on a Dynamic Forms-enabled page.

More details here:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.dynamic_forms_mobile.htm&type=5